# How do I put emacs menubar into Window title bar in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: emacs

While using Ubuntu 14.04, Menus are shown in window title bar.  However if emacs is opened, menus are in the menubar as in older versions of Ubuntu or windows.  Can I menus in window title bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a setting that you can flip in Emacs; it's something that is defined by the version of GTK against which Emacs is compiled (if any), likely some compile-time settings, and your Ubuntu settings. You could compile your own Emacs to enable this, but using a Personal Package Archive to install a pre-built version is much easier.

[This PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-elisp/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) provides an `emacs-snapshot` package that works the way you want. This package is a bleeding-edge build of Emacs, updated frequently, and with some differences from the official Ubuntu `emacs` package. Most notably:

> - Little/no support for installing debian packages of elisp modules. Much of that support exists only in the form of a distropatch, which is not included here. So for example if you were to `apt-get install yaml-mode`, you would have to include "(require 'yaml-mode)" in your init, but you wouldn't be able to autoload yaml-mode like you may be accustomed to with the stable series. I am working on enabling this, but be warned that it is currently broken.
> - On the plus side, package.el works *excellently* and most of the packages you might want to install should be available either from MELPA or Marmalade or similar. In general, if you are using these snapshots you will want to `M-x package-install foo` rather than `apt-get install foo`.

If you want to use it, you can do something like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-elisp/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emacs-snapshot
```

You should be able to have both versions installed concurrently. The one that launches by default when you run `emacs` will depend on your [alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/update-alternatives.8.html). You will also have commands named for each version in case you want to switch back and forth, e.g. `emacs-24.4.50`.

And if you want to just run the snapshot, that works well too. It's generally pretty stable.